# Random Q&A system

Tags: java, android, random

Basically, I made a simple app for my Android, where it picks a random question for you, and picks specific answers.  Only 1 of the answers is correct, while other's aren't.

Also, after editing the `QBegin` method, it started to give me questions but with wrong answers.

```
TextView question; 
private int qType = -1;  
private int asked = 0;

private void QBegin() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    Random random = new Random();
    int qType = random.nextInt(5);
    switch(qType){
    case 0:
        question.setText("Question 1");
        break;
    case 1:
        question.setText("Q2");
        break;
    case 2:
        question.setText("Q3");
        break;
    case 3:
        question.setText("Q4");
        break;
    case 4:
        question.setText("Q5");
        break;
    }
    asked++;

    //intList.add(qType);
    getAnswers(qType);
    /*if(intList.contains(qType) && asked <= 5){
        QBegin();
    } else {
        answerCounter.setText("Congratulations!!! Your score : "+correct);
    }*/
}

private int answer;

private void getAnswers(int Type) {
    Random random = new Random();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(Type){
    case 1:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("относительно низкая температура шлаков");
            answer2.setText("сложность в управлении");
            answer3.setText("малая производительность");
            answer4.setText("нету выделения энергии непосредственно в загрузке");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("сложность в управлении");
            answer2.setText("относительно низкая температура шлаков");
            answer3.setText("малая производительность");
            answer4.setText("нету выделения энергии непосредственно в загрузке");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("сложность в управлении");
            answer2.setText("малая производительность");
            answer3.setText("относительно низкая температура шлаков");
            answer4.setText("нету выделения энергии непосредственно в загрузке");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("сложность в управлении");
            answer2.setText("малая производительность");
            answer3.setText("нету выделения энергии непосредственно в загрузке");
            answer4.setText("относительно низкая температура шлаков");

        }

        break;

    case 2:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("закрытые - плавка под слоем шихты");
            answer2.setText("открытые - плавка на воздухе");
            answer3.setText("вакуумные - плавка в вакууме");
            answer4.setText("компрессорные - плавка под избыточным давлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("открытые - плавка на воздухе");
            answer2.setText("закрытые - плавка под слоем шихты");
            answer3.setText("вакуумные - плавка в вакууме");
            answer4.setText("компрессорные - плавка под избыточным давлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("открытые - плавка на воздухе");
            answer2.setText("вакуумные - плавка в вакууме");
            answer3.setText("закрытые - плавка под слоем шихты");
            answer4.setText("компрессорные - плавка под избыточным давлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("открытые - плавка на воздухе");
            answer2.setText("вакуумные - плавка в вакууме");
            answer3.setText("компрессорные - плавка под избыточным давлением");
            answer4.setText("закрытые - плавка под слоем шихты");

        }

        break;

    case 3:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("в которой тепло выделяется в результате прохождения тока через проводники с активным сопротивлением");
            answer2.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer3.setText("в которой тепло не передаеться тепло излучением");
            answer4.setText("в которой которая делиться на компрессорную печь с активным сопротивлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer2.setText("в которой тепло выделяется в результате прохождения тока через проводники с активным сопротивлением");
            answer3.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer4.setText("в которой которая делиться на компрессорную печь с активным сопротивлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer2.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer3.setText("в которой тепло выделяется в результате прохождения тока через проводники с активным сопротивлением");
            answer4.setText("в которой которая делиться на компрессорную печь с активным сопротивлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer2.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer3.setText("в которой которая делиться на компрессорную печь с активным сопротивлением");
            answer4.setText("в которой тепло выделяется в результате прохождения тока через проводники с активным сопротивлением");

        }

        break;

    case 4:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("Correct");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Correct");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Correct");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Correct");

        }

        break;

    case 5:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("Correct");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Correct");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Correct");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Correct");

        }

        break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The (or at least "One") obvious approach would be to move most of your data into arrays, and just use the numbers to select values from those arrays. For example:

```
private void QBegin() {
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    String[] types = { "Question 1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"};
    Random random = new Random();
    int qType = random.nextInt(types.length);

    question.setText(types[qType]);
    asked++;
    getAnswers(qType);
}
```

Most of `getAnswers` should end up similar, although I'm afraid I'm lack the ambition to type it all in.

Personally, however, I think I'd move the text of the questions and answers out to a text file (or a database) and write the code as a more or less generic "engine" that read and present the questions and answers from the file.

Comment: Good solution, but never use magic numbers, e.g. `random.nextInt(types.length);` is better.

Comment: @Landei: Good point. Edited.